# Proof of conditional probability formula

Tags: probability

Knowing only this:
$P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$

How can i proof this? $P(A\cap C\mid B) = P(A\mid C\cap B).P(C\mid B)$

Comment: Just apply your formula to both sides of the equation and you'll see they're the same

Comment: The formula provided in "knowing only this" applies for all events $A$, $B$, Therefore, you can apply it for the LHS and RHS, e.g. $P(A \cap C | B) = \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C)}{P(B)}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
P(A\cap C\mid B)&=\frac{P((A\cap C)\cap B)}{P(B)}\\
&=\frac{P(A\cap (C\cap B))}{P(C\cap B)}\cdot\frac{P(C\cap B)}{P(B)}\\
&=P(A\mid C\cap B)\cdot P(C\mid B)
\end{aligned}
$$